# External search options box positioned strangely on search page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the [search tips page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search), it looks like the content div isn't wide enough for the text and the external searches box to sit side-by-side like they do on other sites. This is what is looks like on cooking:

[image: search box pushed down]

and here's what it looks like on photography (as an example):

[image: nicely aligned]

Can we get this fixed so the search page doesn't look so awkward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (after rev 2012.5.16.2574).